# Why do I need to call junit.textui.TestRunner? (Java)

Tags: java, junit

I have several questions, actually.

When I have to do javac myTest then java -cp '.:/usr/share/java/junit.jar' junit.textui.TestRunner myTest,

1. Why do I need to call junit.textui.TestRunner ? Is that just the convention? (Considering we only need to call java  after we have compiled the file
2. a) Why do I need to specify the class path, b)and what does it do?
3. a) Why do I have to add junit.textui. in front of TestRunner? b) How does Terminal know where to look when I write junit.textui.TestRunner?
4. When we do java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore [test class name], does org.junit.runner.JUnitCore mean that program is searching the web for the package?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `TestRunner` is a class in the JUnit framework that runs the code in your test class. It has a main method that, when executed, loads your class and runs the test methods you provided.
2. You have to specify the class path so that Java knows where to find your junit.jar file. You could [provide the classpath through an operating system environment variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) so that you don't have to type it in at the command line.
3. `junit.textui` is the package name that the `TestRunner` class is in inside the junit.jar file.  You have to specify this so that Java knows where to look in the JAR file for the class to run. (3a. It looks everywhere in your classpath until it finds the specified class.)
4. No, it's not searching the Web. It finds that class in your classpath. Specifically, it finds it in the junit.jar file.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! Regarding 4, I see org.junit and com.domain and these sound a lot like domain names..

Comment: @B.A. Yes, they are reverse domain names. Package names are used to uniquely identify classes that might have the same names, so companies adopted the convention of using their reversed domain names for package names to ensure uniqueness.